# forumla automatcally filled when another cell value is added - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have: =NETWORKDAYS(N25, AJ25-1) in Column O to calculate the number of busines days since an item has gone out of the building. right now I am manually duplicating it each time a new item goes out.

But is there a way to put a formula that when Column N is filled out, it will automatically added in the formula above in Column O respective to the row?

On that note, it seems my formula is a bit wonky. It works perfectly when it gets to the day AFTER it was sent out (day 1), but if it's sent out today, it will come back with the value -1 or -2 instead of "0" indicating that today's date (AJ25) is the same as the value I entered in on Column N.

I can understand why it does that but not sure how to calculate it so it doens't count today's date but starts the day after.

Comment: You can run an IF statement to check if cells are filled or use a worksheet_change to write the formula in when column N has been filled out. Your formula might be better as `=NETWORKDAYS(N25, MAX(N25, AJ25))-1`

Comment: I tried =if(isblank($N5);"";$P$1) that I found in another similar question, but it didn't really work out. I replaced the $P$1 with the formula above that I mentioned and it worked but it also just appeared as the formula itself rather than the calculated formula.

Comment: Also, your previous revised formula worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you put it in quotes or have the cell formatted as text. `=if(isblank($N25); ""; NETWORKDAYS(N25; MAX(N25; AJ25))-1)`

Comment: I tried that but it keeps coming up with an error. Not sure what I am doing wrong. :(

Comment: Given that your system uses semi-colons as the regional list separator perhaps you have a foreign language version of excel that uses alternate function names. btw, *'it keeps coming up with an error'* is not a valid error description. Or as pnuts has noted maybe you don't even know what your system uses as a list separator.

Comment: @pnuts - Then stated that he/she tried one with semi-colons that was *'found in another similar question'*. I personally don't have a lot of time for someone who apparently doesn't know if their regional system uses a comma or a semi-colon.

Comment: That worked!! Thank you! I changed all semi-colon to commas.

Answer (score 0):

It seems [@Jeeped's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4039065/jeeped) formula met the requirement:

```
=if(isblank($N25), "", NETWORKDAYS(N25, MAX(N25, AJ25))-1)
```